# dojo textbox value is not visible in chrome after using disable attribute

Tags: dojo

I'm using DOJO 1.7 for UI and i have problem with dojo textbox if i disabled a textbox value in that text box is not visible fully gray color is appears in chrome  please help me how to solve it. thanks in advance. and code snippet is:

```
<td><input dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" trim="true" id="testId" name="test" maxlength="10" value="value is there" disable="disable" />
```

Comment: <td><input dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox"
       trim="true" id="testId" name="test" maxlength="10"       value="value is  there" disable="disable"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the `disabled` attribute, not `disable`, so for example:

```
<input dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" trim="true" id="testId" name="test" maxlength="10" value="value is there" disabled="disabled" />
```

This should work fine, also in Google Chrome as you can see in the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NM8R2/).

Comment: Thank you for your response..No its not working anyhow i got solution now its working fine. solution is i had changed claro.css file attribute                        .dj_webkit .dijitTextBoxDisabled INPUT {
 color: black; 
}     i had override color: #eee; to color: black;

Comment: So if you open the fiddle you have the same issue? I'm seeing the text as well (and I'm using Google Chrome too), weird. Which version of Google Chrome do you use?

Comment: i'm using chrome 33 , no its not chrome version issue the above code is  working fine in fiddle but in my project its not working so , that i did R&D on dojo style sheets code . and we are using claro class its not working after changing css its working fine.. thank you for you response brother ...

Comment: You should not have to override the CSS. As you can see it's working fine in my example (which uses the claro CSS as well). I'm pretty sure there's something else that's wrong in your code. If you can reproduce the same behavior in JSFiddle then I'm happy to help.